# Docker Desktop created container do not have access to macos

Tags: docker

I use Docker Desktop run 4 centos containers in my macos.
their IP respectively are:

```
container1: 172.17.0.2/16
container2: 172.17.0.3/16
container3: 172.17.0.4/16
container4: 172.17.0.5/16
```

and they can communicate to each other.
but in my macos(host machine), there is no IP who is in `172.17.0.0/16`.

```
$ ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether a0:99:9b:17:50:07 
    inet6 fe80::c13:2321:d6a6:36fd%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.1.6 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:13:08:b0:ec:c0 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:13:08:b0:ec:c1 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 82:13:08:b0:ec:c0 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 02:99:9b:17:50:07 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 2e:da:d0:65:0a:1a 
    inet6 fe80::2cda:d0ff:fe65:a1a%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
llw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 2e:da:d0:65:0a:1a 
    inet6 fe80::2cda:d0ff:fe65:a1a%llw0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xa 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::c173:c40a:195f:637e%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::577a:f5e5:e601:519a%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xc 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

Now my requirement is I want there is a `172.17.0.0/16` IP on macos machine, so it can communicate with containers which I created.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT-01**

I have a idea, see the below, is it possible to connect the macos host directly to the bridge, then macos can access the containers then.

[image]

Comment: The container-private IP addresses [aren't directly accessible](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#known-limitations-use-cases-and-workarounds) on Docker Desktop.  Use the `docker run -p` option to publish ports from your containers, and connect to `localhost` and the published port.  There's no reason to look up the IP addresses.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks your response, after  I thought about it, is there a way to bridge macos host and the virtual machine? then macos can access to container.